# How to pass constructor arguments in web3.py

Tags: solidity, web3.py

I'm trying to deploy smartcontract with web3.py. below is my simple smart contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract homeAutomation{
  string public greeting;

  constructor(string memory _greet) public {
    greeting=_greet;
  }

  function greet(string memory _gree) public {
    greeting =_gree;
  }
}
```

below is my web3.py code

```
contract = w3.eth.contract(abi=abi, bytecode=bytecode)
K = input('write your greeting:' )
# Get transaction hash from deployed contract
tx_hash = contract.deploy(K,transaction={'from': w3.eth.accounts[0], 'gas': 410000})
# Get tx receipt to get contract address
tx_receipt = w3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)
contract_address = tx_receipt['contractAddress']
```

when I tried this, I am getting error

```
TypeError: deploy() got multiple values for argument 'transaction'
```

so please let me know how to pass constructor argument to deploy function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments should be passed in an array, so just change `K` to `[K]`.

In addition, I recommend that you either specify all the argument names, or you specify none of them, in which case, their order is important:

- `contract.deploy(args=[K],transaction={...}) # order is not important`
- `contract.deploy({...},[K]) # order is important`

See the official documentation for this function [here](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html#web3.contract.Contract.deploy).